# WPF Notify Property on a Child User Control

Tags: wpf, binding, properties

I have a user control UC_A that contains a user control UC_B. Each has a different view model as its data context, VM_A and VM_B respectively, both derived from INotifyPropertyChanged.

A command from VM_A changes stuff that affects a property in VM_B. UC_B has a binding to that property. How can I cause the binding to update? I tried OnPropertyChanged in VM_A but it does not do the job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If VM B changes, then the notification must be raised from there to notify UC B.

Answer (score 0):

To add on what @flq said already,
I don't see what's the problem, if you implemented OnPropertyChanged properly it should `just work`.
i.e. when your View-model-A changes something in the view-model-B - then whatever property is changed in the VM-B should fire off the OnPropertyChanged - from the VM-B - and that'd 'land' into the UC-B lap, as it should.